# The VM size (or combination of VM sizes) required by this deployment cannot be provisioned due to deployment request constraints

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment

I am unable to deploy to Azure after I added one more role

> The VM size (or combination of VM sizes) required by this deployment
>   cannot be provisioned due to deployment request constraints. If
>   possible, try relaxing constraints such as virtual network bindings,
>   deploying to a hosted service with no other deployment in it and to a
>   different affinity group or with no affinity group, or try deploying
>   to a different region.

The CloudService is new. I was expecting that the resources will be scaled to fit my needs.

Comment: i haven't referred refer the below documentation.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2015/03/11/the-vm-size-or-combination-of-vm-sizes-required-by-this-deployment-cannot-be-provisioned-due-to-deployment-request-constraints/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this warning refers to deployment request constraints. You could try deploying to a different geographic location or affinity group or just wait and try again.

When considering the ability to resize virtual machines there are three key concepts that will impact to change the size of your VM.

1. The region in which your VM is deployed.
2. The physical hardware currently hosting your VM.
3. The deployment model used for the VM.

For more details: [Resize virtual machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resize-virtual-machines/)